# How to use Gatsby file system route API for the frontpage

Tags: gatsby

I am using Gatsbys file system route API to create dynamic pages and that is working very well except for the 1 issue.
I can not figure out how to make it work for the Frontpage (https://localhost:8000/)

I created the page file as pages/{Node.url}.tsx

I see it's working e. g. for http://localhost:8000/news, http://localhost:8000/toc, …
But for the frontpage the URL is at http://localhost:8000/**.tsx/** and not as expected at http://localhost:8000/

Any idea on how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an `index.tsx` under `/pages` folder and Gatsby will take it as home page (`/`), creating a resulting URL as `http://localhost:8000/`